# How to check in a new project to Team Foundation Server?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

I created a new project in my solution under a newly created folder. Not just a solution folder. It is placed under a physical folder also.

Say, my original solution is like this:

```
MySolution
 - MySolution.Web
 - MySolution.Domain
```

Now the structure is:

```
MySolution
 - App
   - MySolution.Web
 - Lib
   - MySolution.Domain
   - MySolution.Repositories
   - MySolution.WorkerServices
 - Test
   - MySolution.Specs
   - MySolution.Unit
```

Please note in addition to the newly added projects, `MySolution.Web` and `MySolution.Domain` are moved to a physical subfolder also.

To move `MySolution.Web` into the `App` folder, I moved the files outside Visual Studio and then edit the `MySolution.sln` manually with a text editor so that the project entry can point to the correct physical location.

Since those two projects are almost empty, I don't really care about losing history.

Then I find I could not check in the change to TFS!

I got `Team Foundation Error`, saying `Could not find a part of the path`.

---

As suggested by comments/answers to this question, I have done an `Add Items to Folder` in my Source Control Explorer. Now the new folders and projects have a plus sign ahead of their icons. But the `MySolution.Web` and `MySolution.Domain` still stubbornly exists in the root. If I try to delete them, it says `One or more children have pending changes`. It appears TFS tracking failed to understand what I am doing and pending changes are related to those projects even though they are not in existence physically on my local computer.

How can I fix it? What is the correct way to add a project into another folder?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to add these new folders to source control.

In Source Control Explorer, use the tree view and right-click on the folder *above* the folders you want to add. You should see an "Add Items to Folder" menu item. Click that, and follow the instructions.

Note that all involved folders must be mapped into your workspace in order for this to work.

Comment: Sorry but how can I check "all involved folders must be mapped into your workspace"?

Comment: Try my suggestion. If it works, then they're all mapped.

Comment: Since `MySolution.Web` has been moved from root into the `App` folder, I think I need to delete the `MySolution.Web` project from TFS. But it says `One of more children have pending changes`.

O I messed up the mapping!

Comment: Your question didn't say anything about moved folders! And you probably haven't messed up the mapping at all. That message means you need to check in your changes first.

Comment: My bad. The question has been updated. Now after `Add Items to Folder` I have `MySolution.Web` in `App` folder, but the original project in root folder still exists. How can I remove the one in root?

Comment: Delete it? You'll lose the history, of course. How did you "move" the folder to begin with?

Comment: I don't care about losing history since we just start our work, those projects are almost empty. The "move" happens outside Visual Studio. (just updated my question again to show you).

Comment: Yeah, you'll want to learn to not do this stuff outside of Visual Studio. Even with the "local workspace" feature, TFS isn't going to be able to guess what you want to do. If you use Visual Studio (Source Control Explorer) to do moves like this, then TFS will correctly show them as being rename operations. This will be more important once you have history that you want to keep.

Comment: If I move the project into a solution folder, it will not move to its physical folder. That's why I did it outside Visual Studio. And how can I fix it now?

Comment: Can I just break all the TFS tracking and have a fresh start from now on?

Comment: Now I got a solution. Just move the two projects from the root to their folders anyway. Now I finally have a check-in.